# Linux shell script, parsing each line

Tags: sed, grep, sh

I am facing a problem with my shell script (I'm using SH):

I have a file with multiple line including mail adressess, for example:

```
abcd

plm

name_aA.2isurnamec@Text.com  -> this is a line that checks the correct condition

random efgh

aaaaaa

naaame_aB.3isurnamec@Text.ro   ->same (this is not part of the file)
```

I have used grep to filter the correct mail adresses like this:

grep -E '^[a-z][a-zA-Z_]*.[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+@[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{,12}.(ro|com|eu)$' file.txt

I have to write a shell that cheks the file and prints the following (for the above example it would be like this ):

```
"Incorrect:" abcd

"Incorrect:" plm

"Correct:" name_aA.2isurnamec@Text.com

"Incorrect:" random efgh

"Incorrect:" aaaaaa

"Correct:" naaame_aB.3isurnamec@Text.ro
```

I want to solve this problem using grep or sed, while, if, or pipes etc i dont want to use lists or other things.

I have tried using something like this

```
grep condition abc.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your code goes here
done
```

but it only prints the correct lines, and i know that i can also print the lines that dont match the grep condition using -v on grep, but i want to print the lines in the order they appear in the text file.

I'm having trouble trying to parse each line of the file, or maybe i don't need to parse the lines 1

by 1, i really dont know how to solve it.

If you could help me i would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: The shell i'm using is sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
pattern='^[a-z][a-zA-Z_]*\.[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]+@[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{,12}\.(ro|com|eu)$'

while read line; do
    if [ "$line" ]; then
        if echo "$line" | grep -E -q $pattern; then
            echo "\"Correct:\" $line"
        else
            echo "\"Incorrect:\" $line"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Invoke like this, assuming the bash script is called `filter` and the text file, `text.txt`: `./filter < text.txt`.

Note that the full stops in the regular expression are escaped and that the domain name can contain lowercase letters (although, I think that your regex is too restrictive). Other characters are not escaped because the string is in single quotes.

`while` reads the standard input line by line into `$line`; the first `if` skips the empty lines; the second one checks `$line` against `$pattern` (`-q` suppresses `grep` output).